# Storing technique of Redis Graph

Tags: redis, redisgraph

could anyone please let me know how RedisGraph internally stores Nodes and Edges. Would be great if someone helps. Thank you!

I tried searching about the storage technique but I just got one clue that it uses sparse adjacency matrix which not sufficient for me. I need to know details about this.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes and Relations (Edges) are indeed stored using sparse adjacency matrices. What details do you need?

Comment: Edge will be represented using adjacency matrix, but how nodes will be stored. Do redisgraph stores node's property using a redis hash?